# Calling an HTML table from code behind

Tags: c#-3.0, asp.net-3.5

I am trying to access an HTML table from code behind, and set its visible="false" property (depending on what value the user has selected). The table has an id value and a runat=server attribute.

How can I call the table from the code behind in C# 2008 and set its display?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would wrap the table in an `<asp:Panel` control and change the visible property on that instead.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you have your table set up to run at server.

Example

```
<table id="tblMyTable" runat="server">
....
</table>
```

On server side you can access it by using the variable `tblMyTable`

To hide the visibility is not simple.  There is not a property for it since it is a Html control rather than a server control.

I would wrap the table in an ASP.NET control such as a panel, and hide the panel.

Answer (score 1):

Seting the visibility from the codebehind is a simple as setting the Visible property:

```
table_control.Visible = false;
```

If you are doing this in response to some client side activity, then you need some javascript:

```
document.getElementById("<%= table_control,ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
```

or jQuery:

```
$("#<%= table_control,ClientID %>").hide();
```

Call this from an onclick or onchange event, as needed for your page.

Answer (score 1):

we can hide the table control from server side use the following code in server side at which event you want to hide the table

your html code

```
<table id="tblMyTable" runat="server">
....
</table>
```

your server code in which event you want to hide table

```
tblMyTable.Style.Add("display", "none");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an <asp:Table> control if you want to access the table from code behind eg

```
<asp:Table ID="Table1" CssClass="data" runat="server" CellSpacing="0">
    <asp:TableHeaderRow>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell>SKU</asp:TableHeaderCell>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell>Description</asp:TableHeaderCell>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell>Quantity</asp:TableHeaderCell>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell>Amount</asp:TableHeaderCell> 
    </asp:TableHeaderRow>
</asp:Table>
```

Bind data to the table eg. like so:

```
var row = new TableRow();

row.AddCell(stock.Sku);
row.AddCell(stock.Description);
row.AddCellTextbox("txtQty", cart.Values[key]);
row.AddCell(stock.Price.ToString());

Table1.Rows.Add(row);
```

Note: The table control doesnt provide viewstate for items added in code, for that you need to use a GridView or similar control.

Answer (score 0):

In-order to set the visibility of the Table you need to set the Runat="server" attribute to your table

Design View:
....

Code Behind (C#)
tbl_test.Visible=false;

Try this it works... ;)

Comment: Please improve your answer. Add some description and formatting.